# Change ID img src upon hover another ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I've just gotten the interest to learn about web programming. Encountered a problem and hope someone could show me some directions.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/KdhPG/99/

Current: when hover over the image ID, it changes the text ID color to 'red'

Likewise isn't possible to hover over the text ID to change the current img src of the image ID to another image src/URL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not good at jQuery.. but here is a possible solution using the hover so that the previous image is restored. The image will change as you say when hovering over the text, once the mouse leaves it will restore the previous image:

```
var prevsrc;
$("#one").hover(
    function() {
        prevsrc =  $("#img-one").attr('src');
        $("#img-one").attr('src', 'yourNewImageUrl');    

    },
    function() {
        $("#img-one").attr('src', prevsrc);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#img-one").hover(function() {
    $('#img-one').attr("src","http://aviationhumor.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/chuck-norris.jpg");
}
```

**EDIT:**

As David Thomas mentioned in this case it's better to work with DOM elements like this

```
this.src = 'http://aviationhumor.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/chuck-norris.jpg';
```

Comment: I'd suggest using basic DOM methods, rather than jQuery in this instance: `this.src = 'http://aviationhumor.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/chuck-norris.jpg';` since `this` already refers to the `#img-one` element.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/yDhhr/

That doesn't account for mouseout / unhovering, but you should be able to take this code and do it.

As a side note, using the `attr()` feature of jQuery you can change basically any attribute you want to. It's pretty useful.